# Transform a map from daily data to weekly data in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, java-stream, treemap

I have a map of `LocalDate` and Integer with daily data. Now I want to create a new map with the weekly data, which means new map will contain the cumulative count when we sum up the integers which falls under previous entry and current entry. I am stuck in this. Can anyone please help me in designing an algorithm for this. I am new to Java Stream api, if it is doable using Stream API it will

Example data:
[image: example data]

In the image I have tried traversing the weeklyMap and then inside that traversed the dailyMap. But I am not sure how to make it possible in code(Java).

**EDIT**

Code snippet:

```
Map.Entry<LocalDate, Integer> prevEntry = null;
        boolean firstTime = true;
        for (Map.Entry<LocalDate, Integer> currEntry : weeklyMap.entrySet()) {
            if (firstTime) {
                prevEntry = currEntry;
                firstTime = false;
                if (weeklyMap.containsKey(currEntry.getKey())) {
                    weeklyMap.put(currEntry.getKey(), currEntry.getValue());
                }
            } else {
                for (Map.Entry<LocalDate, Integer> todayEntry : dailyMap.entrySet()) {
                    if (prevEntry.getKey().equals(todayEntry.getKey())) {
                        prevEntry.setValue(todayEntry.getValue());
                    } else if(todayEntry.getKey().isAfter(prevEntry.getKey()) && todayEntry.getKey().isBefore(currEntry.getKey())) {
                        currEntry.setValue(currEntry.getValue() + todayEntry.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Edge cases: What happens in a month with 31 days (> 4 weeks)?  Is there a partial 5th week, or does that 5th week rollover to the start of the next month?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't see why months would come into it at all?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the comment, but I am looking to add the integers from the dailyMap which are falling under the dates of the weeklyMap

Comment: So you're saying that your current map has keys which are weeks, is that right?  I got a different impression from your sample data.  Maybe you should include the code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have tried traversing the weeklyMap and then inside that traversed the dailyMap. But I am not sure how to make it possible in code(Java)

Comment: You should really include your code; it would help your question.

Comment: This is still a bit unclear. What exactly is your input data? Is it just the daily data or is there some initial weekly data, too? Also, from your picture it seems like the end result should be a cumulative sum, i.e. every week also factors in all previous weeks. Is that true?

Comment: @ohlec Yes. The resultant map should be a cumulative sum.

Comment: [The `YearWeek` class of the ThreeTen Extra project](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) could be helpful here (you can also do without it if you don’t want the dependency).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Added the code snippet

Comment: Please take a look at [Fenwick Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree), it's the exact data structure you're needing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems easiest to first build a daily map of cumulative sums, then filter out only the mondays:

```
public static Map<LocalDate, Integer> cumulativeWeeklySum(SortedMap<LocalDate, Integer> data) {
    AtomicInteger cumulativeSum = new AtomicInteger(0);
    return data.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> cumulativeSum.addAndGet(e.getValue())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getKey().getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY || e.getKey().equals(data.lastKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

**edit:**

If you want to retain the order of the resulting map, you can modify the last `collect()` call:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(
             Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
             (v1, v2) -> { throw new RuntimeException("Duplicate key - can't happen"); },
             TreeMap::new));
```

Comment: When I printed this map, it came out to be something like this:

`{2018-10-15=22, 2018-10-08=12, 2018-10-22=27, 2018-10-01=2}`

Is there any way to make it ordered like TreeMap?

Comment: Yes. But some how my dailyMap contains a date `2018-10-23` and it got ignored with this code.

Comment: Well, it should, shouldn't it? `2018-10-23` is a tuesday.

Comment: No, It shouldn't! I have implemented the logic where whatever the last date is, it will consider the last date if it has not been included in the weeklyMap. So whatever is left after `2018-10-22` needs to be summed up and filled in the last entry.

Comment: Ah, OK. That just means the last entry of the cumulatively sorted daily map should be included as well; I've made another edit to reflect that.

Comment: You should change `e.getKey() == data.lastKey()` to `e.getKey().equals(data.lastKey())`

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Absolutely, thanks. Done. Although it isn't really necessary here (the keys *will* be reference-equal, given how the maps are constructed), it's certainly better style.

Comment: @ohlec you are correct, I just saw it and immediately thought it was wrong (I'm just so used to always use equals), but using reference equality is enough in this case.

Comment: @ohlec +1 It helped me alot.. Thank you for your help!! The beer's on me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should include the edge case which verifies the `currentEntry.key == todayEntry.key` and then sum up the previous values.

The code may look somewhat like this:

```
if(todayEntry.getKey().equals(currEntry.getKey())) {
     currEntry.setValue(currEntry.getValue() + todayEntry.getValue() + prevEntry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, but I have accepted the answer which is solving the problem using Stream API, as the question said so.